# Xcode 7 - OSX Server 5 - Xcode Bots and Submodules?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, git-submodules, bots

Attempting to set up Xcode Bots on my main repository with Xcode 7, I'm running into some strange issues.

I've been able to setup a bot on this server for:

• A public repo on Github via ssh.

• A private repo on Github via ssh.

My main repository however is a private repo with submodules, and it always fails when attempting to checkout these submodules.

The issue seems to be that it's not using SSH to check out these submodules, as the errors I get are along these lines:

`Authentication:Anonymous Authentication -> The server SSH fingerprint failed to verify`

or

`Authentication:Anonymous Authentication -> The source control operation failed because no working copy could be found.`

I can see no where in Xcode 7's Bots creation flow to set these to use SSH, where as in Xcode 6.4 I could set the keys and everything. Instead I just see a list of submodules with checkboxes next to them when prompted to Verify Credentials and fix them.